# how to concert this to javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, case

I have a banner to publish. My actual code for html form is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebsite.com/bzLoader.js"></script>
<noscript>
  <p style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;padding:1em;">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas le Javascript ou a été désactivé.</p>
</noscript>
<div id="1234ABCS"></div>
<div id="QSDF98765"></div>
```

How can I translate this code into a javascript code ?

I need to insert this code inside this other javascript code (where it is written //Banner 1) :

```
   var parts = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/'),
   page = parts[parts.length - 1];

switch (page)
{
case "index.html":
  //Banner 1
  break;
case "index_en.html":
  //Banner 2
  break;
}
```

And if I'm not wrong, the last step to get everything again back in html form is to put everything inside this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> my javascript code </SCRIPT>
```

Right ??

It would be really appreciated help for me :)

Comment: You're not going to benefit anything by trying to output the banner (in its entirety) with javascript, especially given the `<noscript>` portion.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I tried many ways but nothing getting displayed when I try to mix together the first part of my code with the second one. What do you suggest instead ??

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can do in JavaScript.

The `noscript` tag can't be inserted from JavaScript since there is no JavaScript when you need it.

What you need to do is to add this code to your web server; the server must send the correct HTML banner to the browser. Trying to insert the correct banner on the client / in the browser is a bad approach.

Comment: This is due to a specificic of my software who. I'm forced to act this way. Can you just help me to write the correct way my html code into my second part code ? Thanks

Comment: You can use `document.write()` to add code if you put the `script` tag in the place where the code should appear. Otherwise, you must locate the element (for example with `document.getElementById()` which you want to modify and replace it's content (for example by using `innerHTML`). But `noscript` won't have any effect if you do this.